# Can someone explain this proof that perfect compact Hausdorff spaces are uncountable?

Tags: general-topology

It is in this pdf, called Theorem 2 on the second page:

http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~m54x12/m54lecture17.pdf

So I understand that we have a sequence of points $x_1, x_2, ...$

I understand that we can find a non-empty open set $V_1$ so that $x_1$ is not contained in the closure of $V_1$, just by applying the "claim" to $x_1$ in the whole space $X$.

However I don't understand why we are able to continue on in this process to get a $V_2$ INSIDE of $V_1$ whose closure does not contain $x_2$. After all, $x_2$ could be anywhere in the space; it does not have to be in $V_1$. So it doesn't seem right to apply the "claim" to $x_2$ in $V_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that claim states that we can find a (suitable) $V\subset U$ whether or not $x\in U$.

If $V_1$ does not contain $x_2$, then it's ***especially*** easy to get a $V_2$ inside of $V_1$ not containing $x_2$; in fact, the interior of any closed subset of $V_1$ will do.  If, on the other hand, $x_2$ ***is*** in $V_1$, this claim becomes particularly useful.